# Visual Studio for Mac - Autocomplete doesnt work anymore since mfractor

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xaml, autocomplete, intellisense

Im using Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac.

I installed [mfractor](https://www.mfractor.com/). Ever since I installed it my autocompletion in `xaml` does not work anymore and I do not know how to fix it. I tried to disable mfractor and I even uninstalled it but nothing helped. Two Examples:

1. Before I could type `<SL` after the very first character `S` I was able to see a few options to autocomplete. After writing the two characters `SL` I could autocomplete it to `StackLayout`. Not anymore. I dont see a list for autocompletion. I have to manually type every single char and I will never see a list for autocomplete options.
2. When typing `<StackLayout>` after typing `>` there was another autocomplete that I could choose `</StackLayout`. Well not anymore. I have to type everything myself.

Does anyone know something about this problem and maybe even know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the Mac and VS, uninstalling/disabling mfractor a few teams I had to realize that nothing worked.

But I accidentally found a way to fix it. I created a few `Forms ContentPage XAML` files in hope of that fixing something and got this message: `You´ve reached your limit of two MFractor-enabled XAML files for today. Upgrade to Mfractor Professional for unlimited use.`

Since then my autocompletion works again. Even with Mfractor enabled.

Comment: Hi, so glad to hear that your issue is solve, you can mark you reply as answer and that will help others to easier search this information, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @axbeit, I’m Matthew Robbins, the founder of MFractor. Did MFractor break your default XAML intellisense when it was installed and it reached its free usage limit? If so, we need to fix this. Could you please email me (matthew@mfractor.com) Visual Studio Mac version information and log files so that I can get this fixed?